# How can I make the function in setTimeout execute completely?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

New to js,I want to output 5 '!'s with a 1-second interval,and finally output "end".
I thought the problem was related to asynchronization.
I have tried a lot of times and a lot of methods such as "await,async" and "promise" ,but still failed.

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.cnt = 5;
  }

  real() {
    this.cnt--;
    console.log("!");
  }

  getCnt() {
    return this.cnt;
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    this.a = new A();
  }
  fun() {
    if (this.a.getCnt() > 0) {
      this.a.real();
      setTimeout(() => this.fun(), 1000);
    }
  }
}

class C {
  constructor() {
    this.b = new B();
  }
  f() {
    this.b.fun();
    console.log("end");
  }
}
var c = new C();
c.f();
```

Comment: try using async await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping the complexity of the 3 classes involved, this is elegantly solved with `async` functions. (Without async functions, the cascade of `setTimeout`s in a loop becomes more difficult to manage.)

This can of course be wrapped into a trio of classes if required.

```
// Turns `setTimeout` into a promise you can `await`.
async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// Calls a function `fun` `times` times, delaying for `delayTime` ms between each invocation.
// Since this is an async function, it returns a promise that will resolve as soon as it's done,
// which in turn can be awaited upon.
async function repeatWithDelay(fun, times, delayTime) {
  for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    await fun(i);
    await delay(delayTime);
  }
}

// Prints the number passed in (could just print an exclamation mark).
function print(i) {
  console.log(`${i}!`);
}

async function main() {
  console.log("Go!");
  await repeatWithDelay(print, 5, 500);
  console.log("Done!");
}

// Assumes top-level `await` is not available in your environment.
// If it is, this too can be replaced with a simple `await`.
main().then(() => {
  console.log("Main done.");
});
```

This prints out

```
Go!
0!
1!
2!
3!
4!
Done!
Main done.
```

Comment: Amazing answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you need to make your method `fun` be able to report when it is finished as it is an asynchronous method (calls `setTimeout`). The best way to do this is return a `Promise` which allows calls to use `await` on it

```
fun() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {    
      
      const exec = () => {
        if (this.a.getCnt() > 0) {
          this.a.real();
          setTimeout(exec.bind(this), 1000);
        }
        else{
          resolve();
        }
      }
      
      exec.apply(this);
    })
  }
```

Once you've done that, also mark function `f` as `async` which allows you to call `await` inside it:

```
async f() {
  await this.b.fun();
  console.log("end");
}
```

And then all works as expected:

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.cnt = 5;
  }

  real() {
    this.cnt--;
    console.log("!");
  }

  getCnt() {
    return this.cnt;
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    this.a = new A();
  }
  fun() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {    
      
      const exec = () => {
        if (this.a.getCnt() > 0) {
          this.a.real();
          setTimeout(exec.bind(this), 1000);
        }
        else{
          resolve();
        }
      }
      
      exec.apply(this);
    })
  }
}

class C {
  constructor() {
    this.b = new B();
  }
  async f() {
    await this.b.fun();
    console.log("end");
  }
}

var c = new C();
c.f();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write a generic function that emulate typing, hope this help you understand async/await functions

```js
let fakeConsole = document.getElementById('console');

async function sleep(time) {
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, time));
}

function type(text) {
  fakeConsole.innerHTML += text;
}

async function emulateTyping(text, speed) {
  // split the text into an array of characters;
  const characters = text.split('').reverse();
  if (characters.length > 0) {
    // display first character right away
    type(characters.pop());
    while (characters.length > 0) {
      // wait <speed> millisections
      await sleep(speed);
      // type one character
      type(characters.pop());
    }
  }
}

async function main() {
  // async function we wait for the end with "await"
  await emulateTyping("!!!!!", 500);
  // sync function
  type(' END');
};

main();
```

```html
<pre id="console"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I will try to get your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

If using promise, then you need to resolve the response in `setTimeout` too

```js
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.cnt = 5;
  }

  real() {
    this.cnt--;
    console.log("!");
  }

  getCnt() {
    return this.cnt;
  }
}

class B {
  constructor() {
    this.a = new A();
  }
  fun() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      if (this.a.getCnt() > 0) {
        this.a.real();
        setTimeout(() => resolve(this.fun()), 1000);
      } else {
        resolve()
      }
    })

  }
}

class C {
  constructor() {
    this.b = new B();
  }
  f() {
    this.b.fun().then(() => {
      console.log("end");
    })

  }
}
var c = new C();
c.f();
```

For multiple loops:

```
var loop = [array of 100 items];
await Promise.all(
   loop.map(async (item) => await this.b.fun();)
)

console.log("end");
```

Comment: Thank you a lot and your code is useful and amazing.But if there is a loop in f(),for example, c will call b.fun() for 10 times, how can I refine the code?

Comment: Just updated my answer, hope it'll help

Comment: Sorry, can loops like "for" or "while" be used? I have to call a function like b.fun for more than 100 times and I have to use loops.

Comment: @SNORLAX Edited again